# Matlab quadprog parameters for L1 Regularization

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, quadratic-programming

I've been struggling with the parameterization of quadprog function in Matlab for a problem like this:

[image]

where x is a matrix of x 0 w 0 +x 1 w 1 +x 2 2 w 2   and y is the target vector containing a value for each row of x, w is the weight vector, lambda is a scalar value.

I have tried this, but I'm sure it's not correct:

```
N = size(x, 2);
Sigma = cov(x);
H = 2.0*Sigma;
c = zeros(N,1);
quadprog(H, c)
```

Could someone please guide me with what the parameters should be for the quadprog function?

Answer (score 2):

This optimization problem is known as Lasso, and as you wrote it it is not formally a quadratic program. You can either convert it to a quadratic program, see [this link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/119795/quadratic-programming-and-lasso), or you can use Matlab's builtin [lasso](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/lasso.html) (part of Statistics toolbox)